# php check if number exists in database

Tags: php, mysql

basically i dont want duplicate number in certain field. how do i do that?

```
table user:
id   name    group
1    a        2
2    b        3
3    c        1
4    d        6
5    e        5

$q = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(t_group) FROM user");
$r = $q->fetch_row;
if($r[0] > 0) :
     $rand_no = rand(1,10);
     $db->query("INSERT INTO user(name, group) VALUES('$name','$rand_no')");
endif;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate just slightly more on what it is you are trying to accomplish? And why are you using rand()? It will never guarantee that you don't get duplicates (far from it).

Comment: Why not just make that field unique in the database?

Comment: I agree re: unique enforcement via database. If it is that important to data integrity, don't rely on your code. Double plus especially if you are not using a class or library to handle all database interfacing since you will need to remember to implement it every time everywhere you update the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use `insert ... where not exists`**

Example code

```
//prevent those pesky SQL injection attacks
$rand_no = mysql_real_escape_string($rand_no);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

//Only insert if group is not already used
$db->query("insert into user(name, `group`) 
            VALUES('$name',$rand_no) 
            where not exists 
              (select `group` from user where `group` = '$rand_no') )";
```

I've added the first two lines to remind you no to forget to escape those values to prevent SQL-injection attacks. *(if `$rand_no` is generated by the php code, there's no need to escape it of course, but if a user can manipulate it then you should)*

Secondly `group` is a reserved word, if you want to use it in a query you need to bracket it in backquotes ' ` '.

**EDIT:**
**Enforce it in the database**
Set the field `group` to be a unique field using `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN `group` `group` UNIQUE
```

Comment: You need to add that $group = rand(1,10);

Comment: If the group already exists, won't there be no action taken with this statement? This does not alert php that nothing was done. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Dutchie432, the query should return the number of rows affected. If 0 rows are affected no inserts where made. If 1 or more the insert was succesfull.

Comment: @boyee007 that's because you are trying to insert a duplicate value into the `group` column, which is the very thing the query is preventing. Also make sure you have backticks around group

Comment: @Johan - Noted. Learned a new tidbit. +1

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

```
var stop_cycle = 0;

while (!stop_cycle) {

$rand_no = rand(1,10);
$db->query("SELECT group FROM user WHERE group = ".$rand_no);

// check if query returns any result
if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0)  {

// value is unique, let's insert it
 $db->query("INSERT INTO user(name, group) VALUES('$name','$rand_no')");

// end cycle
 stop_cycle=1;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to generate a random number and then see if there is already a record with that number in the field. Lets say your random number is `8`

```
select top 1 group from user where group=8
```

If any rows return, the number is not unique.